# Как можно добавить функция rand()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как можно добавить функция rand() на результат?

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM user_friend RIGHT JOIN user ON
        (user.`user_id` = user_friend.`friend_user_id_1`
    OR
        user.`user_id` = user_friend.`friend_user_id_2`)
    AND
        user.`user_id` != '$user_id'
    WHERE
        user_friend.`friend_user_id_1` = '$user_id'
    OR
        user_friend.`friend_user_id_2` = '$user_id' LIMIT 9";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$friend = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($friend) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $number++;
        $user_url = $row['user_url'];
        $user_mini_avatar = $row['user_mini_avatar'];
        echo '<div id="friend_'.$number.'"><a href="'.$user_url.'"><img src="images/'.$user_mini_avatar.'" /></a></div>';
    }
} else
    echo "У вас нет друзей :(";
?>
```

Comment: Что в конечном итоге требуется получить? Что именно должно быть случайным?

Comment: @Regent, $friend то есть результат

Comment: Куда добавить? Что добавить? Потрудитесь хотя бы объяснить задачу.

Comment: @Etki мне нужно чтобы результат был рандом  `$result = mysql_query($query);`

Comment: @KYRAN тогда перед `LIMIT 9` можно добавить `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выборка элементов в случайном порядке осуществляется с помощью `ORDER BY RAND()`.
Последняя строка запроса будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
user_friend.`friend_user_id_2` = '$user_id' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9
```

Стоит отметить, что подобная сортировка работает достаточно медленно.